# What is the best way make node RunAction to be synchronized when executing CCSequence

Tags: cocos2d-x

how can i NOT continue with the flow of the game until i execute RunAction that contains CCSequence of actions. 
is running

```
while(!bEndSequence)
{
    .. stop app form continue ... 
}
```

and in the CCSequence the last action will trigger the bEndSequence to true or false 
is it the only way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d-x is not multithreaded so a while loop (such as the example you give) wouldn't just prevent progress, it'd freeze the game. Instead, what you can do is to create a callback function that triggers the rest of what you want to do, for example:

```
void MyClass::waitToExecute()
{
   //code that you want to delay until after the sequence goes here
}
```

Then you can simply add that callback to the end of your sequence as another action to perform.

```
runAction(CCSequence::create( CCFadeIn::create(TRANSITIONSPEED*1.1f),CCDelayTime::create(TRANSITIONSPEED*0.5), CCFadeOut::create(TRANSITIONSPEED*2.4f), CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(MyClass::waitToExecute)), NULL));
```

Of course, this REALLY depends on how your code works, so there's no way I can objectively say this is the BEST way. But in a lot of situations this will work just fine.